# Microsoft SQL server 2016, cannot create sequence

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have Microsoft SQL server 2016, I am using SSMS to do my DB work. I am trying to create sequences and I keep getting this error

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.seq_changeid As int START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

> Error
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'SEQUENCE'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression or an xmlnamespaces clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

I have tried it in SQLCMD and it does not work there as well. This is local database that i am using for some testing. I login using SQL Server Authentication.

I even tried `select * from sys.sequences` and it errors
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid object name 'sys.sequences'

Comment: What is the result of `select @@version` ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.1399.06 (Intel X86)   Oct 14 2005 00:33:37   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) . Interesting!!!!.

Comment: So: "Microsoft SQL Server **2005**" That version is not 2016 & does not support Sequences.

Comment: You have a database of version 2005 and I am guessing your SSMS is of 2016.

Comment: I do also have a SQL server 2005 service running. I am not sure how i ended up creating a local on 2005. I am going to uninstall 2005 and may be try creating a DB again

Comment: My guess is that your install of 2016 is a named instance. You just need to change the server you connect to. No need to uninstall 2005. Or you would also need to uninstall 2016 and reinstall as the default instance after removing 2005.

Comment: a quick way to see instance names is to open services.msc and look for sql server the instance name is in parentheses.

Comment: I have unistalled 2005, that removed the services SQLEXPRESS2005, I still do see a service SQLEXPRESS. Would 2016 have SQLEXPRESS2016